# Is there a simple way to remove multiple spaces in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose this string:

```
The   fox jumped   over    the log.
```

Turning into:

```
The fox jumped over the log.
```

What is the simplest (1-2 lines) to achieve this, without splitting and going into lists?

Comment: What is your aversion to lists?  They are an integral part of the language, and " ".join(list_of_words) is one of the core idioms for making a list of strings into a single space-delimited string.

Comment: @Tom/@Paul: For simple strings, (string) join would be simple and sweet.  But it gets more complex if there is other whitespace that one does NOT want to disturb... in which case "while" or regex solutions would be best.  I've posted below a string-join that would be "correct", with timed test results for three ways of doing this.

Answer (score 906, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(' +', ' ', 'The     quick brown    fox')
'The quick brown fox'
```

Comment: This solution only handles single space characters. It wouldn't replace a tab or other whitespace characters handled by \s like in nsr81's solution.

Comment: That's true, `string.split` also handles all kinds of whitespaces.

Comment: I prefer this one because it only focuses on the space character and doesn't affect characters like '\n's.

Comment: This does not work for strings _beginning_ or _ending_ in at least one space.

Comment: Yes right. But before that strip() should be done. It will remove spaces from both end.

Comment: You can use `re.sub(' {2,}', ' ', 'The     quick brown    fox')` to **prevent redundant replacements of single-space with single-space**.

Comment: what if a string has single space on ends?

Comment: This works, but is 1/6th the speed of the join/split solution below from @TaylorLeese

Comment: `\s` can be used to match other types of whitespace, or an array `[ \t]` if one of the chars should be ignored

Comment: I found this solution helpful, especially for my Pandas DataFrame where I have a column of strings with extra spaces. Pandas string method accepts regular expression: `df.columnName.str.replace(' +', ' ')` where df is a Pandas DataFrame.
(In Pandas, this replace method was faster than a split/join method `df.columnName.str.split().str.join(' ')`).

Comment: For the lazy ones who can't browse through all answers. `re.sub('\s{2,}', ' ', text)` will replace all consecutive whitespace characters (tabs, newlines etc.) with a single space.

Comment: This fails in pypy-3.6 actually :(

Comment: This doesn't work in python3 can anyone fix it?

Comment: Why import a module when not necessary?

Comment: `' '.join(the_string.split(' '))` also keeps other whitespaces. (13 years later)

Answer (score 839):

`foo` is your string:

```
" ".join(foo.split())
```

Be warned though this removes "all whitespace characters (space, tab, newline, return, formfeed)" (thanks to [hhsaffar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1380151/hhsaffar), see comments). I.e., `"this is  \t a test\n"` will effectively end up as `"this is a test"`.

Comment: “Without splitting and going into lists...”

Comment: I ignored "Without splitting and going into lists..." because I still think it's the best answer.

Comment: This removes trailing spaces. If you want to keep them do: text[0:1] + " ".join(text[1:-1].split()) + text[-1]

Comment: 6x faster than the re.sub() solution, too.

Comment: @nerdfever.com how would you verify that it is 6x faster?

Comment: It is not obvious what this line of code does at first glance. Others will have hard time figuring out why would you split and back join the string. The regex answer is more explicit about what it does.

Comment: Use `"\n".join(" ".join(line.split()) for line in foo.splitlines())` if you want to preserve the newline character

Comment: @fonzane `str.split()` with no specified character to split on by default splits on any whitespace character. It returns a list of all words (groups of non-whitespace characters). `" ".join` then joins that list together with a single space between each word.

Comment: combine with an apply and use it on pandas

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP's reasons for wanting to avoid splitting and joining, but I can tell you mine: When working with my large dataframe, the split + rejoin uses so much memory it crashes. (I use PythonAnywhere and they kill the process.) The re.sub does not.

Comment: Sorry didn't work for me in python3

Comment: The `re`-module also uses `lists`. To only strip consecutive repeated spaces one can use `' '.join(the_string.split(' '))`. This will also remove the leading and trailing spaces but will keep newlines, tabs, etc.

Comment: My impression of the asker's "Without splitting and going into lists" requirement is that they don't want a solution where they must work with lists.  So, this solution fits that requirement.  The result is a string, not a list.  A list is involved in the computation.  That's insignificant.

Comment: WRT speed, the split/join solution is about 4.6x faster than the re.sub one. `s = 'The   fox jumped    over    the log.'; print(timeit(lambda: re.sub(r' +', ' ', s))/timeit(lambda: ' '.join(s.split())))`

Answer (score 137):

```
import re
s = "The   fox jumped   over    the log."
re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", s)
```

or

```
re.sub("\s\s+", " ", s)
```

since the space before comma is listed as a *pet peeve* in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), as [mentioned by user *Martin Thoma*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/simple-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string#comment44543608_1546245) in the comments.

Comment: I'd tend to change that regex to `r"\s\s+"` so that it doesn't try to replace already-single spaces.

Comment: If you wanted that behavior, why not just `"\s{2,}"` instead of a workaround for not knowing moderately-advanced regex behavior?

Comment: remember that sub() does not change the input string `s`, but return the new value.

Comment: @BenBlank Why is it bad if the regex replaces already-single spaces? Is that computationally more intensive? Why? What happens with each replacement operation?

Comment: @moose — It's a readability optimization than a performance one.  `\s+` would cause the line to read "replace *one* or more spaces with a space", rather than "replace *two* or more spaces with a space".  The former immediately makes me stop and think "Why replace one space with one space?  That's silly."  To me, that's a (very minor) code smell.

I actually wouldn't expect there to be any performance difference at all between the two, as it's going to be copying into a new string anyway, and has to stop and test regardless of where the space is being copied *from*.

Comment: @BenBlank: Ok, thank you. You also seem to want the space in `"\s\s+" , " "` before the `,` although it is against [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves). Could you please explain why?

Comment: @moose — I assume that's just a typo on the part of the original poster.  I certainly wouldn't recommend it.  :-)

Comment: @BenBlank I've corrected this typo and he reverted it. So he seems to want it.

Comment: I'd advise against `\s\s+` because this won't normalize a TAB character back to a normal space. a SPACE + TAB does get replaced this way.

Comment: I would also `strip()` (aka trim) the string before doing this as you probably do not want leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: This seems to outperform the accepted answer here form Josh

Answer (score 65):

Using regexes with "\s" and doing simple string.split()'s will *also* remove other whitespace - like newlines, carriage returns, tabs.  Unless this is desired, to **only** do *multiple spaces*, I present these examples.

I used [11 paragraphs, 1000 words, 6665 bytes of Lorem Ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com) to get realistic time tests and used random-length extra spaces throughout:

```
original_string = ''.join(word + (' ' * random.randint(1, 10)) for word in lorem_ipsum.split(' '))
```

The one-liner will essentially do a strip of any leading/trailing spaces, and it preserves a leading/trailing space (but only *ONE* ;-).

```
# setup = '''

import re

def while_replace(string):
    while '  ' in string:
        string = string.replace('  ', ' ')

    return string

def re_replace(string):
    return re.sub(r' {2,}' , ' ', string)

def proper_join(string):
    split_string = string.split(' ')

    # To account for leading/trailing spaces that would simply be removed
    beg = ' ' if not split_string[ 0] else ''
    end = ' ' if not split_string[-1] else ''

    # versus simply ' '.join(item for item in string.split(' ') if item)
    return beg + ' '.join(item for item in split_string if item) + end

original_string = """Lorem    ipsum        ... no, really, it kept going...          malesuada enim feugiat.         Integer imperdiet    erat."""

assert while_replace(original_string) == re_replace(original_string) == proper_join(original_string)

#'''
```

---

```
# while_replace_test
new_string = original_string[:]

new_string = while_replace(new_string)

assert new_string != original_string
```

---

```
# re_replace_test
new_string = original_string[:]

new_string = re_replace(new_string)

assert new_string != original_string
```

---

```
# proper_join_test
new_string = original_string[:]

new_string = proper_join(new_string)

assert new_string != original_string
```

**NOTE:** <s>The "`while` version" made a copy of the `original_string`, as I believe once modified on the first run, successive runs would be faster (if only by a bit).  As this adds time, I added this string copy to the other two so that the times showed the difference only in the logic.</s>  [Keep in mind that the main `stmt` on `timeit` instances will only be executed once](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit); the original way I did this, the `while` loop worked on the same label, `original_string`, thus the second run, there would be nothing to do.  The way it's set up now, calling a function, using two different labels, that isn't a problem.  I've added `assert` statements to all the workers to verify we change something every iteration (for those who may be dubious). E.g., change to this and it breaks:

```
# while_replace_test
new_string = original_string[:]

new_string = while_replace(new_string)

assert new_string != original_string # will break the 2nd iteration

while '  ' in original_string:
    original_string = original_string.replace('  ', ' ')
```

---

```
Tests run on a laptop with an i5 processor running Windows 7 (64-bit).

timeit.Timer(stmt = test, setup = setup).repeat(7, 1000)

test_string = 'The   fox jumped   over\n\t    the log.' # trivial

Python 2.7.3, 32-bit, Windows
                test |      minum |    maximum |    average |     median
---------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------
  while_replace_test |   0.001066 |   0.001260 |   0.001128 |   0.001092
     re_replace_test |   0.003074 |   0.003941 |   0.003357 |   0.003349
    proper_join_test |   0.002783 |   0.004829 |   0.003554 |   0.003035

Python 2.7.3, 64-bit, Windows
                test |      minum |    maximum |    average |     median
---------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------
  while_replace_test |   0.001025 |   0.001079 |   0.001052 |   0.001051
     re_replace_test |   0.003213 |   0.004512 |   0.003656 |   0.003504
    proper_join_test |   0.002760 |   0.006361 |   0.004626 |   0.004600

Python 3.2.3, 32-bit, Windows
                test |      minum |    maximum |    average |     median
---------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------
  while_replace_test |   0.001350 |   0.002302 |   0.001639 |   0.001357
     re_replace_test |   0.006797 |   0.008107 |   0.007319 |   0.007440
    proper_join_test |   0.002863 |   0.003356 |   0.003026 |   0.002975

Python 3.3.3, 64-bit, Windows
                test |      minum |    maximum |    average |     median
---------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------
  while_replace_test |   0.001444 |   0.001490 |   0.001460 |   0.001459
     re_replace_test |   0.011771 |   0.012598 |   0.012082 |   0.011910
    proper_join_test |   0.003741 |   0.005933 |   0.004341 |   0.004009
```

---

```
test_string = lorem_ipsum
# Thanks to http://www.lipsum.com/
# "Generated 11 paragraphs, 1000 words, 6665 bytes of Lorem Ipsum"

Python 2.7.3, 32-bit
                test |      minum |    maximum |    average |     median
---------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------
  while_replace_test |   0.342602 |   0.387803 |   0.359319 |   0.356284
     re_replace_test |   0.337571 |   0.359821 |   0.348876 |   0.348006
    proper_join_test |   0.381654 |   0.395349 |   0.388304 |   0.388193    

Python 2.7.3, 64-bit
                test |      minum |    maximum |    average |     median
---------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------
  while_replace_test |   0.227471 |   0.268340 |   0.240884 |   0.236776
     re_replace_test |   0.301516 |   0.325730 |   0.308626 |   0.307852
    proper_join_test |   0.358766 |   0.383736 |   0.370958 |   0.371866    

Python 3.2.3, 32-bit
                test |      minum |    maximum |    average |     median
---------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------
  while_replace_test |   0.438480 |   0.463380 |   0.447953 |   0.446646
     re_replace_test |   0.463729 |   0.490947 |   0.472496 |   0.468778
    proper_join_test |   0.397022 |   0.427817 |   0.406612 |   0.402053    

Python 3.3.3, 64-bit
                test |      minum |    maximum |    average |     median
---------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------
  while_replace_test |   0.284495 |   0.294025 |   0.288735 |   0.289153
     re_replace_test |   0.501351 |   0.525673 |   0.511347 |   0.508467
    proper_join_test |   0.422011 |   0.448736 |   0.436196 |   0.440318
```

For the trivial string, it would seem that a while-loop is the fastest, followed by the Pythonic string-split/join, and regex pulling up the rear.

**For non-trivial strings**, seems there's a bit more to consider.  32-bit 2.7?  It's regex to the rescue!  2.7 64-bit?  A `while` loop is best, by a decent margin.  32-bit 3.2, go with the "proper" `join`.  64-bit 3.3, go for a `while` loop.  Again.

In the end, one can improve performance *if/where/when needed*, but it's always best to [remember the mantra](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast):

1. Make It Work
2. Make It Right
3. Make It Fast

IANAL, YMMV, Caveat Emptor!

Comment: I would have prefered if you had tested the simple `' '.join(the_string.split())` as this is the usual use case but I'd like to say thank you for your work!

Comment: @wedi: Per other comments (like from [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/a-simple-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string-in-python/15913564#comment1403367_1546251); [user984003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/a-simple-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string-in-python/15913564#comment26654990_1546883), though her/his solution is presumptive and won't work "in all cases"), this sort of solution doesn't adhere to the questioner's request.  One may use .split(' '), and a comp/gen, but gets hairier to deal with lead/trailing spaces.

Comment: @wedi: E.g.: `' '.join(p for p in s.split(' ') if p)` <-- still lost lead/trailing spaces, but accounted for multiple spaces.  To keep them, must do like `parts = s.split(' '); (' ' if not parts[0] else '') + ' '.join(p for p in s.split(' ') if p) + (' ' if not parts[-1] else '')`!

Comment: Thanks @pythonlarry for the mantra!  and love the detailed test!  I'm curious to know if your thoughts or views have changed on this since its been 6 years?

Comment: Missing version that use generators

Comment: @Lee, could you provide an example of your thoughts on a generator version, please?

Comment: @pythonlarry i added answer with two additional versions.

Comment: Why did you make it so complex?

Answer (score 60):

I have to agree with Paul McGuire's comment. To me,

```
' '.join(the_string.split())
```

is vastly preferable to whipping out a regex.

My measurements (Linux and Python 2.5) show the split-then-join to be almost five times faster than doing the "re.sub(...)", and still three times faster if you precompile the regex once and do the operation multiple times. And it is by any measure easier to understand -- *much* more Pythonic.

Comment: This removes trailing spaces. If you want to keep them do: text[0:1] + " ".join(text[1:-1].split()) + text[-1]

Comment: a simple regexp is much better to read. never optimize for performance before you need to.

Comment: @gcb: Why not? What if you're expecting a high throughput scenario (e.g. because of high demand)? Why not deploy something you expect to be less resource intensive from the get go in that scenario?

Comment: @HassanBaig if you already have the performance requirement, then it isn't really premature optimization, right? My point is for when you don't need to obsess about performance yet, it is always better to aim for readability.

Comment: @gcb  'Never optimize for performance before you need to', sounds like a revenue model for an IT business. Also I find a simple `regex` more difficult to read, so to me that's a matter of preference. `Split` and `join` are widely used and are available without importing extra modules. When it comes to software, one should be foresight and prepared for some scenarios. Most developers make this mistake and customers start to complain after a while. Software must be able to handle known unforeseen situations. Speed, stability, security and -> uniformity is far more important than readability.

Comment: To only strip consecutive repeated spaces one can use `' '.join(the_string.split(' '))`. This will also remove the leading and trailing spaces but will keep newlines, tabs, etc.

Answer (score 22):

Similar to the previous solutions, but more specific: replace two or more spaces with one:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "The   fox jumped   over    the log."
>>> re.sub('\s{2,}', ' ', s)
'The fox jumped over the log.'
```

Comment: Why are you repeating answer?

Answer (score 18):

I have tried the following method and it even works with the extreme case like:

```
str1='          I   live    on    earth           '

' '.join(str1.split())
```

But if you prefer a regular expression it can be done as:

```
re.sub('\s+', ' ', str1)
```

Although some preprocessing has to be done in order to remove the trailing and ending space.

Comment: Leading and trailing spaces could be easily removed by str1.strip() then pass it to your re.sub() as follows re.sub(' +', ' ', str1.strip())

Answer (score 18):

```
import re

Text = " You can select below trims for removing white space!!   BR Aliakbar     "
  # trims all white spaces
print('Remove all space:',re.sub(r"\s+", "", Text), sep='') 
# trims left space
print('Remove leading space:', re.sub(r"^\s+", "", Text), sep='') 
# trims right space
print('Remove trailing spaces:', re.sub(r"\s+$", "", Text), sep='')  
# trims both
print('Remove leading and trailing spaces:', re.sub(r"^\s+|\s+$", "", Text), sep='')
# replace more than one white space in the string with one white space
print('Remove more than one space:',re.sub(' +', ' ',Text), sep='')
```

***Result: as code***

```
"Remove all space:Youcanselectbelowtrimsforremovingwhitespace!!BRAliakbar"
"Remove leading space:You can select below trims for removing white space!!   BR Aliakbar"     
"Remove trailing spaces: You can select below trims for removing white space!!   BR Aliakbar"
"Remove leading and trailing spaces:You can select below trims for removing white space!!   BR Aliakbar"
"Remove more than one space: You can select below trims for removing white space!! BR Aliakbar"
```

Answer (score 16):

A simple soultion

```
>>> import re
>>> s="The   fox jumped   over    the log."
>>> print re.sub('\s+',' ', s)
The fox jumped over the log.
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the string splitting technique in a Pandas DataFrame without needing to use .apply(..), which is useful if you need to perform the operation quickly on a large number of strings. Here it is on one line:

```
df['message'] = (df['message'].str.split()).str.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 11):

Solution for Python developers:

```
import re

text1 = 'Python      Exercises    Are   Challenging Exercises'
print("Original string: ", text1)
print("Without extra spaces: ", re.sub(' +', ' ', text1))
```

Output: 
`Original string: Python      Exercises    Are   Challenging Exercises
 Without extra spaces: Python Exercises Are Challenging Exercises`

Comment: this is using regex (google it) but basically ' +' means one or more spaces...so basically I'm replacing one or more spaces with a single space.

Answer (score 10):

This regex will do the trick in Python 3.11:

```
re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)
```

The accepted answer of this thread did not work for me in Python 3.11 on Mac:

```
re.sub(' +', ' ', 'The     quick brown    fox') # does not work for me
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import re
string = re.sub('[ \t\n]+', ' ', 'The     quick brown                \n\n             \t        fox')
```

This will remove all the tabs, new lines and multiple white spaces with single white space.

Comment: But if you have whitespace (non-printable) characters not in your range like '\x00' to '\x0020' the code will not strip them.

Answer (score 6):

This one does exactly what you want

```
old_string = 'The   fox jumped   over    the log '
new_string = " ".join(old_string.split())
print(new_string)
```

Will results to

```
The fox jumped over the log.
```

Answer (score 4):

One line of code to remove all extra spaces before, after, and within a sentence:

```
sentence = "  The   fox jumped   over    the log.  "
sentence = ' '.join(filter(None,sentence.split(' ')))
```

Explanation:

1. Split the entire string into a list.
2. Filter empty elements from the list.
3. Rejoin the remaining elements* with a single space

*The remaining elements should be words or words with punctuations, etc. I did not test this extensively, but this should be a good starting point. All the best!

Answer (score 4):

The fastest you can get for user-generated strings is:

```
if '  ' in text:
    while '  ' in text:
        text = text.replace('  ', ' ')
```

The short circuiting makes it slightly faster than [pythonlarry's comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15913564/4936905). Go for this if you're after efficiency and are strictly looking to weed out extra whitespaces *of the single space variety*.

Answer (score 4):

`" ".join(foo.split())` is not quite correct with respect to the question asked because it also *entirely* removes single leading and/or trailing white spaces. So, if they shall also be replaced by 1 blank, you should do something like the following:

```
" ".join(('*' + foo + '*').split()) [1:-1]
```

Of course, it's less elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'this is a            string with    multiple spaces and    tabs'
>>> str = re.sub('[ \t]+' , ' ', str)
>>> print str
this is a string with multiple spaces and tabs
```

Answer (score 3):

In some cases it's desirable to replace consecutive occurrences of every whitespace character with a single instance of *that* character. You'd use a regular expression with backreferences to do that.

`(\s)\1{1,}` matches any whitespace character, followed by one or more occurrences of that character. Now, all you need to do is specify the first group (`\1`) as the replacement for the match.

Wrapping this in a function:

```
import re

def normalize_whitespace(string):
    return re.sub(r'(\s)\1{1,}', r'\1', string)
```

```
>>> normalize_whitespace('The   fox jumped   over    the log.')
'The fox jumped over the log.'
>>> normalize_whitespace('First    line\t\t\t \n\n\nSecond    line')
'First line\t \nSecond line'
```

Answer (score 3):

Quite surprising - no one posted simple function which will be much faster than ALL other posted solutions. Here it goes:

```
def compactSpaces(s):
    os = ""
    for c in s:
        if c != " " or (os and os[-1] != " "):
            os += c 
    return os
```

Comment: How is this faster?! you're using a loop to go across the entire string. If this is a super large string it might take a long time. Regex is faster. That's not to mention that you took 5 lines when regex does it in 1 line. I prefer avoiding loops whenever possible.

Answer (score 3):

Because @pythonlarry asked here are the missing generator based versions

The groupby join is easy. Groupby will group elements consecutive with same key. And return pairs of keys and list of elements for each group. So when the key is an space an space is returne else the entire group.

```
from itertools import groupby
def group_join(string):
  return ''.join(' ' if chr==' ' else ''.join(times) for chr,times in groupby(string))
```

The group by variant is simple but very slow. So now for the generator variant. Here we consume an iterator, the string, and yield all chars except chars that follow an char.

```
def generator_join_generator(string):
  last=False
  for c in string:
    if c==' ':
      if not last:
        last=True
        yield ' '
    else:
      last=False
    yield c

def generator_join(string):
  return ''.join(generator_join_generator(string))
```

So i meassured the timings with some other lorem ipsum.

- while_replace 0.015868543065153062
- re_replace 0.22579886706080288
- proper_join 0.40058281796518713
- group_join 5.53206754301209
- generator_join 1.6673167790286243

With Hello and World separated by 64KB of spaces

- while_replace 2.991308711003512
- re_replace 0.08232860406860709
- proper_join 6.294375243945979
- group_join 2.4320066600339487
- generator_join 6.329648651066236

Not forget the original sentence

- while_replace 0.002160938922315836
- re_replace 0.008620491018518806
- proper_join 0.005650000995956361
- group_join 0.028368217987008393
- generator_join 0.009435956948436797

Interesting here for nearly space only strings group join is not that worse
Timing showing always median from seven runs of a thousand times each.

Answer (score 1):

```
def unPretty(S):
   # Given a dictionary, JSON, list, float, int, or even a string...
   # return a string stripped of CR, LF replaced by space, with multiple spaces reduced to one.
   return ' '.join(str(S).replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'This is a             string full of spaces          and taps'
string = string.split(' ')
while '' in string:
    string.remove('')
string = ' '.join(string)
print(string)
```

**Results**:

> This is a string full of spaces and taps

Answer (score 0):

To remove white space, considering leading, trailing and extra white space in between words, use:

```
(?<=\s) +|^ +(?=\s)| (?= +[\n\0])
```

The first `or` deals with leading white space, the second `or` deals with start of string leading white space, and the last one deals with trailing white space.

For proof of use, this link will provide you with a test.

https://regex101.com/r/meBYli/4

This is to be used with the [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.split) function.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read a lot into the other examples, but I have just created this method for consolidating multiple consecutive space characters.

It does not use any libraries, and whilst it is relatively long in terms of script length, it is not a complex implementation:

```
def spaceMatcher(command):
    """
    Function defined to consolidate multiple whitespace characters in
    strings to a single space
    """
    # Initiate index to flag if more than one consecutive character
    iteration
    space_match = 0
    space_char = ""
    for char in command:
      if char == " ":
          space_match += 1
          space_char += " "
      elif (char != " ") & (space_match > 1):
          new_command = command.replace(space_char, " ")
          space_match = 0
          space_char = ""
      elif char != " ":
          space_match = 0
          space_char = ""
   return new_command

command = None
command = str(input("Please enter a command ->"))
print(spaceMatcher(command))
print(list(spaceMatcher(command)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This does and will do: :)

```
# python... 3.x
import operator
...
# line: line of text
return " ".join(filter(lambda a: operator.is_not(a, ""), line.strip().split(" ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution ever!

```
a = 'The   fox jumped   over    the log.'
while '  ' in a: a = a.replace('  ', ' ')
print(a)
```

Output:

```
The fox jumped over the log.
```

Comment: The challenge is to tackle multiple spaces. The number of these spaces are not fixed.

Hence a fixed length replace approach is ineffective.

Comment: @FarhanHaiKhan Please read the code well. This is NOT a fixed length replace approach so your downvote is on wrong and unfair basis.

Comment: Please note that I called it ineffective and not incorrect. The number of this iterations this can run for a big string is insane, and that's why it's been downvoted. In other words "Can you do better than that?"

Comment: @FarhanHaiKhan please read the requirements again. He says "What is the SIMPLEST (1-2 lines) to achieve this". He's asking for simplicity not speed. This is literally 1 line solution and it meets the requirements. Once again your downvote is on wrong and unfair basis.

Comment: There's a one liner for this using re.sub, simple and effective. Are you implying this is "simpler" in any way?

Comment: @FarhanHaiKhan Yes, my solution is simpler and shorter. First, mine is a one liner and Second, re.sub is 2 liner because you have to import a library and it's difficult to understand for beginners. Your down vote is unfair and is pure arrogance given that you didn't read the requirements of the question and just making new requirements that he didn't ask for. This is counter productive and not encouraging people who are actually trying to help beginners.