# Python .format slice long string and add dots

Tags: python, string

In Python, How can I make long string "Foo Bar" became "Foo..." by using advance formatting 
and don't change short string like "Foo"?

```
"{0:.<-10s}".format("Foo Bar")
```

just makes string fill with dots

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python truncate a long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872512/python-truncate-a-long-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use a separate function for that; the Python format mini language does not support truncating:

```
def truncate(string, width):
    if len(string) > width:
        string = string[:width-3] + '...'
    return string

"{0:<10s}".format(truncate("Foo Bar Baz", 10))
```

which outputs:

```
>>> "{0:<10s}".format(truncate("Foo", 10))
'Foo       '
>>> "{0:<10s}".format(truncate("Foo Bar Baz", 10))
'Foo Bar...'
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not take into account the fact that removing the last three characters of the original string may result in a string ending with a space.

With this input:

```
"{0:<10s}".format(truncate("Foo Ba rBaz", 10))
```

the output is:

```
'Foo Ba ...'
```

with as space before the three dots.

This is a fix:

```
def truncate(string, width):
    string = string.strip()
    if len(string) > width:
        string = string[:width-3].strip() + '...'
    return string
```

Now `"{0:<10s}".format(truncate("Foo Ba rBaz", 10))` outputs `'Foo Ba... '`

Answer (score -2):

You can configure how many number of dots you need and after how many number of characters. I am assigning 10 dots after 3 characters

```
text = "Foo Bar"
dots = "." * 10
output = text[0:3] + dots
print output
```

The output is:

```
Foo..........
```

Comment: Your solution will print dots even when the text isn't truncated or the lenght isn't gerater than the minimum.