# python flask template return first 150 characters

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to create meta description on my website, in this moment i have this function for get product description :

```
{{ product.description|nl2br }}
```

Need edit this function for get only the first 150 characters for create meta description, is possible this in template ? or need create this function in views.py ?

Comment: may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872512/python-truncate-a-long-string

Comment: is not duplicate, I'm need in flask template not in python, in python is easy, just put  [0:150]

Comment: so you can use , as in twig , the | truncate function http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/text.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

jinja2 has a filter named `truncate`, the documentation is [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#truncate):

```
{{ "foo bar baz"|truncate(9) }}
-> "foo ..."
```

so, you can try this one:

```
{{ product.description | truncate(150) }}
```