# Trunk long strings in format - Python

Tags: python, string, format, long-integer, trunk

I'm printing this table in Python:

```
          NOMBRE        POBLACIÓN ENFERMOS  SANOS  RATA
       Chile        17000000     0    17000000 0.00 
     Hanslandia      2000000  2000000     0    1.00 
     Bastiland       4000000     0     4000000 -0.01
        Peru        31000000     0    31000000 0.00 
      Bolivia       10000000 10000000     0    1.00 
     Argentina      43000000     0    43000000 0.00 
    Henryboysnia     4200000  4200000     0    1.00 
     Inglaterra     51000000     0    51000000 0.00 
Dondeeldiabloperdioelponcho 500000      0     500000  0.00 
   Laquebradelaji   11000000 11000000     0    1.00 
      Uruguay        2000000     0     2000000 0.00 
      Paraguay       4000000     0     4000000 0.00 
      Suriname       500000      0     500000  0.00 
     Venezuela      31000000 31000000     0    1.00 
   Fantasilandia     3000000     0     3000000 -0.01
        USA         300000000    0    3000000000.00 
       NotUSA       20000000     0    20000000 -0.01
       Mexico       127000000    0    1270000000.00 
     Happyland       5000000     0     5000000 -0.01
UvuvwevweOnyetenyevweUgwembubwemOssas13000000     0    13000000 -0.01
```

using this format line code:

```
print("{0: ^20}{1: ^9.0f}{2: ^9.0f}{3: ^9.0f}{4: ^5.2f}".format(mundo[country].name,mundo[country].inhabitants,mundo[country].sick[i],mundo[country].healthy[i],mundo[country].rata[i]))
```

The thing is, there's this string `vuvwevweOnyetenyevweUgwembubwemOssas` that's too long and makes the other columns see all disordered. I've researched and, supposedly, if I do `{0:. ^20}`, the `.` would trunk the string to 20 characters, but what I get when I get that dot is the first column aligned to the left. Any idea why, and how can I do this?

Comment: [Python truncate a long string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2872512/669576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number after the caret `^` specifies the total width, which is used for the alignment. The number after the dot `.` is used to trim the string, see the language [spec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

```
>>> "{0:^20.20}".format("This-is-much-to-long-to-fit")
'This-is-much-to-long'

>>> "{0:^20.20}".format("sort")
'        sort        '
```

You should also have a look at [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate).