# Designing an expandable command-line interface with lists

Tags: python, command-line-interface

These are the three lists I have:

```
# made up data
products = ['apple','banana','orange'] 
prices = ['£0.11','£0.07','£0.05']
dates = ['02/04/2017','14/09/2018','06/08/2016']
```

### Important to know

- The data in these lists will vary along with its size, although they will maintain the same data type.
- The first elements of each list are linked, likewise for the second and third element etc...

### Desired command line interface:

```
Product | Price | Date of Purchase
--------|-------|------------------
 apple  | £0.11 |    02/04/2017
--------|-------|------------------
 banana | £0.07 |    14/09/2018
--------|-------|------------------
 orange | £0.05 |    06/08/2016
```

I want to create a table like this. It should obviously continue if there are more elements in each list but I don't know how I would create it.

### I could do

```
print(""" Product | Price | Date of Purchase   # etc...
          --------|-------|------------------
              %s  |   %s  |     %s 
""" % (products[0],prices[0],dates[0]))
```

But I think this would be hardcoding the interface, which isn't ideal because the list has an undetermined length

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried Pandas?

Comment: I have not heard of it, is it needed?

Comment: You can easily do it using pandas library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a version that doesn't utilize a library, here's a fairly simple function that makes use of some list comprehensions

```
def print_table(headers, *columns):
    # Ignore any columns of data that don't have a header
    columns = columns[:len(headers)]

    # Start with a space to set the header off from the left edge, then join the header strings with " | "
    print(" " + " | ".join(headers))
    # Draw the header separator with column dividers based on header length
    print("|".join(['-' * (len(header) + 2) for header in headers]))

    # Iterate over all lists passed in, and combine them together in a tuple by row
    for row in zip(*columns):
        # Center the contents within the space available in the column based on the header width
        print("|".join([
            col.center((len(headers[idx]) + 2), ' ')
            for idx, col in enumerate(row)
        ]))
```

This doesn't handle cell values that are longer than the column header length + 2. But that would be easy to implement with a truncation of the cell contents (an example of string truncation can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872512/python-truncate-a-long-string)).

Answer (score 1):

Try pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
products = ['apple','banana','orange'] 
prices = ['£0.11','£0.07','£0.05']
dates = ['02/04/2017','14/09/2018','06/08/2016']

df = pd.DataFrame({"Product": products, "Price": prices, "Date of Purchase": dates})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Product  Price Date of Purchase
0   apple  £0.11       02/04/2017
1  banana  £0.07       14/09/2018
2  orange  £0.05       06/08/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import beautifultable
from beautifultable import BeautifulTable
table = BeautifulTable()
# made up data
products = ['apple','banana','orange'] 
prices = ['£0.11','£0.07','£0.05']
dates = ['02/04/2017','14/09/2018','06/08/2016']

table.column_headers=['Product' ,'Price','Date of Purchase']
for i in zip(products,prices,dates):
    table.append_row(list(i))
print(table)
```

output is :

```
+---------+-------+------------------+
| Product | Price | Date of Purchase |
+---------+-------+------------------+
|  apple  | £0.11 |    02/04/2017    |
+---------+-------+------------------+
| banana  | £0.07 |    14/09/2018    |
+---------+-------+------------------+
| orange  | £0.05 |    06/08/2016    |
+---------+-------+------------------+
```