# How to format long SQL queries according to PEP8

Tags: python, python-2.7, pep8

According to [PEP 8 (Maximum Line Length)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), a line should never be longer than 79 characters.

When I try to split up queries, however, I run into issues like continuation characters, and invalid tokens, etc.

For example, what would be the best way to format this query, according to PEP8?

```
cursor.execute("SELECT pivot_id FROM aud_qty WHERE hshake1 is NULL AND ((strftime('%s', DATETIME('now')) - strftime('%s', sent_to_pivot)) / (60)) > 30;")
```

Comment: I believe that this question deserves a better explanation, regarding the example and the concept itself. Maybe some long time Pythonist could give a more clear vision for both situations. I opened this question at Quora, in order to get more explanations for the subject: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-respect-PEP-8-Maximum-Line-Length-79-characters-for-SQL-queries-without-causing-issues-to-my-code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What about

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT pivot_id
                    FROM aud_qty
                   WHERE hshake1 is NULL
                     AND ((strftime('%s', DATETIME('now')) -
                         strftime('%s', sent_to_pivot)) / (60)) > 30;
               """)
```

? Using `"""` or `'''` you get the same behaviour as a very long string but you can use newlines just fine. And your database won't mind them either.

Comment: Are all of the extra spaces sent over the network to the database when running this query? Is this commonly considered negligible?

Comment: @avatarofhope2 you could put the query in a variable and [clean it up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546245/157171) before execution.

Answer (score 3):

In this way you have a clearly looking SQL statement that complies with PEP8 guidelines.

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT pivot_id
    FROM aud_qty
    WHERE hshake1 is NULL
        AND ((strftime('%s', DATETIME('now')) -
            strftime('%s', sent_to_pivot)) / (60)) > 30;
""")
```

Comment: Phase add an explanation, for long term value, and to help others learn from this code. Choose only answers are frowned upon on SO. For example, what is the important part of this answer that was not known by the OP, how does it solve the issue, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use multiline strings. If you declare your string with just one `"` or `'`, it will be a single line string, to create multiline strings, you need to wrap your string with `"""` or `'''`. Here is an example:

```
sql_query = """SELECT pivot_id 
FROM aud_qty 
WHERE hshake1 is NULL AND 
    ((strftime('%s', DATETIME('now')) - strftime('%s', sent_to_pivot)) / (60)) > 30;"""
```

It's worth mentioning that creating SQL queries manually is usually not a good idea, as it can enable SQL injection attacks and lead to other problems.

Answer (score 0):

how bout

```
from models import AudQty,session
update_limit = time.time()-30*60 # 30 minutes ago
session.query(AudQty.pivot_id).filter(hshake1=None,
                                sent_to_pivot_lte=update_limit).all()
```

strings can also be multiline without triple quotes, as two quotes strings next to each other automagically concatenate

```
cursor.execute("SELECT pivot_id FROM aud_qty " 
               "WHERE hshake1 is NULL AND "
               "((strftime('%s', DATETIME('now')) - strftime('%s', sent_to_pivot)) / (60)) > 30;")
```

Comment: Is this SQL Alchemy you are using?

Comment: yes the first example is sqlalchemy(I was kind of being a smart ass)