# how to remove blank spaces ( not new lines ) and "/n" from file

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have lot of files which are not formatted properly.

The data is something like this

```
select *                  from table1 \n , table2
  select cnt(1) from                          table3
```

How can i remove unnecessary blank spaces and "/n"

result

```
select * from table1,table2
select cnt(1) from table3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`\n` or `/n`?

Comment: it is \n and not /n

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/a-simple-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string

Comment: I dont want to do on string but on entire file.

Comment: You have to read the file, and then you get a string. after removing the spaces just write the results back to the file.

Comment: Isn't this quite different from the other questions mentioned by Doron? The OP doesn't want some of the spaces to be retained. For example, spaces around commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this but i think the idea will work for any number of spaces before a comma and not just one like the previous answer which was more simple but not as practical. For every line in the file we look at every word of that line, but we make an empty list for for each line that will be fixed. if the word in the line is  a " " or "\n" we do not append it.
then we go through the new list and print out the word plus a space if it not equal to a comma.

```
 for line in file:
        wordl = []
        strng = ""
        for word in line:
            if word != " " or word != "\n":
                wordl.append(word)
        for w in wordl:
            if w != ",":
                strng += w + " "
            else:
                strng += w
    print strng
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by:

```
s = 'select *                  from table1 \n    ,     table2'
result = " ".join(s.split()).replace(' , ', ',')
print result
```

> > **Output:** select * from table1,table2

Comment: What if the string is `select *                  from table1 \n , table2` like the OP's example?

Comment: I fixed it, by replacing " , " with ","