# remove white spaces between special characters and words python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove all white spaces between special characters and words.

For example,

```
"My Sister  '  s boyfriend is taking HIS brother to the movies  .  "
```

to

```
"My Sister's boyfriend is taking HIS brother to the movies."
```

How to do this in Python?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solutions like [Simple way to remove multiple spaces in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/simple-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string) don't work because they're just removing the duplicate spaces, so it would leave the spaces around dot and quote.

But can be done simply, with regex, using `\W` to determine non-alphanum (including spaces) and removing spaces before & after that (using `\s*` not `\s+` so it can handle start & end of the string, not as satisfying because it performs a lot of replacements by the same thing, but simple & does the job):

```
import re

s = "My Sister ' s boyfriend is taking HIS brother    to the movies ."

print(re.sub("\s*(\W)\s*",r"\1",s))
```

result:

```
My Sister's boyfriend is taking HIS brother to the movies.
```

Comment: Thank you! but Im still having a white space between movies and .   :((

Comment: edited, to handle the dot in the end doesn't have space after it. Which wasn't the case in your question. Whatever, now that works even if it _ends_ with dot.