# Remove spaces around metacharacters with regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to get rid of any space that is around  a non-alphanumeric character without removing the said character like `/\s*(\W)\s*/g` would by default.

Is there a way to target only the spaces with .replace()?

e.g.:

```js
var regex = "/\s*(\W)\s*/g";
var text = "Words  : \"  text docs\"";
var text = text.replace(regex , "");
console.log(text)
```

expected text :"Words:"text docs"

Something like [remove white spaces between special characters and words python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237635/remove-white-spaces-between-special-characters-and-words-python/47237671#47237671) but in javascript

Comment: What's wrong with your regex? (Well, I'd use `[^\w ]` instead of `\W` so as to not match a space.)

Comment: add your expected text please

Comment: You want to replace text with first group in JavaScript? eg. `text.replace(/\s*(\W)\s*/g , "$1")` ??

Comment: Thank you Ritesh, your solution works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bear in mind that `\W` matches any "non-word" character that is not an ASCII letter, digit, or `_`. `\W`, in JS regex, is equal to `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`. Thus, it also matches whitespace that you need to remove. To be able to only match non-whitespace non-word chars, you need to replace `\W` with a `[^\w\s]` pattern.

So, the rest is just replacing the match with the [**replacement backreference**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to the Group 1 value, which is `$1` in JS:

```
text = text.replace(/\s*([^\w\s])\s*/g , "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FXQktk/1)

JS demo:

```js
console.log("Some - text +=@!#$#$^%* here .        ".replace(/\s*([^\w\s])\s*/g , "$1"))
```

Comment: Enrico Maria De Angelis and Ritesh Khandekar suggested both of the fixes in comments , thank you for the link to explanation of replacement backreference