# replace multispaces into a single space from a series in a dataframe and return it back to the series

Tags: python, whitespace

I have multi-column dataframe of Flickr tags with 41,000 rows. I want to remove multiple white spaces element in a column, leaving the other columns intact.

so, this is how my column looks like:

```
column1                            column2                                              column3
<a href="www.asia.com>Breda</a>    result    thisIs    Somany     multiplespace   s     25,000
```

and this is how I want my column2 looks like after I remove multiple white spaces in it:

```
column1                            column2                                 column3
<a href="www.asia.com>Breda</a>    result thisIs Somany multiplespace s    25,000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['column2'] = df['column2'].replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
```

will do your job, `s\+` stands for more then one whitspace.

You can use this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/simple-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string) to get another idea of it how it works, the command `replace` works with it.

Comment: it works. thanks. but I also found another way. thanks by the way @PV8

Comment: works like a charm in only some seconds for 41,000 rows compare to for loops. thanks @PV8

Answer (score 0):

it also works using function like this code below. it is a good functino to use to different columns.

```
 def replaceWhiteSpace(text):
    res = []
    for i in text:
        res = text.str.split()
    res = res.str.join(' ')
    return res

df['column2'] = replaceWhiteSpace(df['column2'])
```

Comment: to be honest this is a `loop`solution, you should avoid that! a vectorized approach is better  (python preferred solotion) :) but good one also

Comment: what do you mean by a vectorized approach? is it like your answer?

Comment: excally, the moment you don't see a `for`, `while` it is vectorized most of the time