# Python re negative lookbehind assertion if following pattern allows repetitions

Tags: python, negative-lookbehind, python-re

I can't make negative lookbehind assertion work with the python re module if the following pattern allows repetitions:

```
import re

ok = re.compile( r'(?<!abc)def' )
print( ok.search( 'abcdef' ) ) 
# -> None (ok)
print( ok.search( 'abc def' ) )
# -> 'def' (ok)

nok = re.compile( r'(?<!abc)\s*def' )
print( nok.search( 'abcdef' ) ) 
# -> None (ok)
print( nok.search( 'abc def' ) )
# -> 'def'. Why???
```

My real case application is that I want to find a match in a file only if the match is not preceded by 'function ':

```
# Must match
mustMatch = 'x = myFunction( y )'

# Must not match
mustNotMatch = 'function x = myFunction( y )'

# Tried without success (always matches)
tried = re.compile( r'(?<!\bfunction\b)\s*\w+\s*=\s*myFunction' )
print( tried.search( mustMatch  ) ) 
# -> match
print( tried.search( mustNotMatch  ) )
# -> match as well. Why???
```

Is that a limitation?

Comment: `nok = re.compile( '(?<!abc)\s*def' )` should be `nok = re.compile( r'(?<!abc)\s*def' )`

Comment: @ChrisCharley, while the use of raw string is needed, the logic of the pattern itself is wrong too.

Comment: @ChrisCharley thanks, I've corrected it in the question but as JvdV mentionned the problem has a deeper root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *" -> 'def'. Why???"*

Well, it's quite logical. Look at your pattern: `(?<!abc)\s*def`

- `(?<!abc)` - Negative lookbehind for places that are not preceded by `abc`, still generates all but one position in your string
- `\s*` - Zero or more spaces
- `def` - litally matching def

Thus, returning `def` as a match. To make more sense of this, here a small representation of the positions that are still valid after the negative lookbehind:

[image]

As you can see, still 7 valid positions. And including `\s*` does not affect anything since `*` means ***zero*** or more.

So first apply what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546244/9758194) and then apply a pattern something like: `(?<!\bfunction\b\s)\w+\s*=\s*myFunction` to retrieve your matches. There may be neater ways though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I naively thought that the "main" pattern, '\s*def', would be sought first and that the match would then be checked against the lookbehind condition. Since the lookbehind pattern must be of fixed with, I don't see how to solve my issue though

Comment: @jxrossel, well one thing you could look at is a check with [`startswith`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm) once you retrieve your match. Another option is to first trim your strim from multiple spaces (I guess that's why you have `s*`. So first apply what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546244/9758194) and then apply a pattern something like: `(^|(?<!\bfunction\b\s))\w+\s*=\s*myFunction` to retrieve your matches.

Comment: @jxrossel, done. Good luck with future endeavours. I'll be glad to assist.

Comment: As a better alternative, knowing that `function` might only be at the beginning (with indentation): `(?m)^(?!\s*\bfunction\b).*?myFunction`. The negative lookahead allows for non-fixed string length and can be followed by anything of interest. The only limitation I've found is that one cannot skip wrapped lines starting by `function`