# How to replace a string with a backspace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, str-replace

[`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) allows to replace a substring in a string with something else.

I have the problem of repeated whitespaces after the replacement:

```
>>> 'word word to be removed word'.replace('to be removed', '')
'word word  word'
```

Note the two whitespaces after the second `word`.

Is there a way to replace a substring with a backspace that would remove one space? (I know that the string will be made of words separated by spaces)

Comment: Well, in your own words, why do two spaces appear? Can you think of a substring that you could remove from the original text, in order to get the result you want?

Comment: Alternatively remove [multiple spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string)

Comment: Add a space after "`remove`" - ....`.replace('to be removed ', '')`. You can get rid of the problem.

Comment: `\w*` also your friend, so *spoiler* instead use `r'\w*to be removed\w*'`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: well, I cannot - and this is why I asked the question :) `\b` did not work

Comment: also consider all the other kind of punctuation that could occur, and group that into `[` `]` e.g. `[ ,.;;']*` or what have you

Comment: How would you expect a backspace to work though? Assuming you know that you want to replace `'  '` with it, would it not replace `'  '` with a backspace and in the process remove the `'o'` from `'to'` as well since its replacing and not just adding the backspace in? If all you want to do is replace double spaces with single spaces, a simple `str.replace('  ', ' ')` would suffice.

Comment: @RazzleShazl -1: the built-in `.replace` method of strings *in Python* does not use regex at all.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel good to know and probably a good reason to avoid this method unwieldy method :)

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to `split()`, and then `join()` the result. This also removes pre-and post-whitspaces

```
>>> ' '.join('word word to be removed word'.replace('to be removed', '').split())
'word word word'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add this whitespace at the end of the substring to be removed:

```
phrase = 'word word to be removed word'

# We add the whitespace at the end
to_remove = 'to be removed ' # instead of 'to be removed'

# Remove a specific substring
phrase = phrase.replace(to_remove, '')
```

If you have consecutive whitespaces and want to replace them by only one, you can use a regex:

```
import re

# Replace all consecutive whitespaces by one whitespace
phrase = re.sub(r" +", " ", phrase)
```