# How to remove extra spaces from the data which is being entered

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, strip

I am trying to remove the extra space from the data which is entered as input.

I tried using the `.strip()` condition but it doesn't remove the extra space of the entered data.

**the code I wrote to remove extra space**

```
Data_1 = input("Enter your name:", )
print(Data_1.strip())
```

Comment: Your code is working as expected. Please provide the input data that has an issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. Please provide a [mre] including input, expected output, and actual output. You can [edit] the question. Check out [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: You might be looking for this: [Is there a simple way to remove multiple spaces in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1546226/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are 3 ways of dealing with spaces you can use according to your needs:

#### 1- the method you are using

`.strip()`  method removes whitespaces at the beginning and end of your input string.

if your input string `Data_1` is `"    john "` or `"Edward  luther "` or `"  Stephanie"`

doing `Data_1.strip()` returns `"john"` or `"Edward  luther"` or `"Stephanie"` with no extra spaces at the beginning and at the end

#### 2- removing all spaces

if what you want is remove all the spaces inside a string like `"Edward Hamilton luther  "`

you can simply use `Data_1.replace(" ", "")`, that will remove all whitespaces and result in `"EdwardHamiltonluther"`

#### 3- removing excessive whitespaces

if you want to remove excessive whitespaces in a string
for example `"  Edward    Hamilton   is a     nice guy  "`

you can use `" ".join(Data_1.split())`

it will return `"Edward Hamilton is a nice guy"`

try it :

```
Data_1 = input("Enter your name:", )
print(" ".join(Data_1.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

.strip() removes the whitespaces in the front and end of the string. To remove the extra spaces, you can try replace them.

```
Data_1 = input("Enter your name:", )
print(Data_1.replace("  ", "").strip())
```

Output -

```
Enter your name:  E  lon Mu  s  k 
Elon Musk
```