# replace multiple non-space characters in python string

Tags: python, string

Uniting multiple spaces to one space character in a python string is doable ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string)), but what about uniting non-space-characters?

```
>>> name = "the__answer____is___42"
>>> print("_".join(list(filter(lambda x: x != '', name.split("_")))))
the_answer_is_42
```

Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: Do you have an example of the input `name`?

Comment: @user56700 yes sorry, updated the question

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't have to call `list` here; it's just (possibly) more efficient to do so, based on how `str.join` and `list` each handle arbitrary iterable values.

Comment: You can also use `None` in place of `lambda x: x !=''` (as it represents a predicate that accepts truthy values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is:

> 1. `split()` the original string into a list by `'_'`.
> 2. Remove all empty strings from this list by `if not x==''`.
> 3. Use `'_'.join()` on this list.

That would look like this (working code example) :

```
# original string
targetString = "the__answer____is___42"

# answer
answer = '_'.join([x for x in targetString.split('_') if not x==''])

# printing the answer
print(answer)
```

You can make that more compact by putting it into a function:

```
def shrink_repeated_characters(targetString,character):
    return character.join([x for x in targetString.split(character) if not x==''])
```

In `shrink_repeated_characters()` given above, the parameter `targetString` is the original string, and `character` is the character you want to merge, eg. `'_'`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string):

```py
>> import re
>> re.sub('_+', '_', 'the__answer____is___42')
'the_answer_is_42'

# if u have more than one non-space char
>> re.sub(r'([_ ])+', r"\1", 'the__answer____is___42')
'the_answer_is_42'

>> re.sub(r'([_ ])+', r"\1", 'the  answer    is   42')
'the answer is 42'
```