# How to use strip to substring in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with 100,000 rows and 300 columns

Here is the sample dataset:

```
    EVENT_DTL
0   8. Background : no job / living with         marriage_virgin 9. Social status : doing pretty well with his family

1   8. Background : Engineer / living with his mom marriage_married
```

How can I remove the white blank between *with* and *marriage_virgin* but leave only one white blank?

Desired outout would be:

```
        EVENT_DTL
    0   8. Background : no job / living with marriage_virgin 9. Social status : doing pretty well with his family
    
    1   8. Background : Engineer / living with his mom marriage_married
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to replace `"\s+"` (1 or more whitespace) by a single whitespace.

Try this :

```
df["EVENT_DTL"]= df["EVENT_DTL"].str.replace("\s+", " ", regex=True)
```

Output :

```
print(df)
                                                                                                   EVENT_DTL
0  8. Background : no job / living with marriage_virgin 9. Social status : doing pretty well with his family
1  8. Background : Engineer / living with his mom marriage_married
```

If you need to clean up the whole dataframe, use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) :

```
df.astype(str).replace("\s+", " ", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I always thought `DataFrame.str` methods were replicas of the standard library string methods, so I didn't think to check the api. This looks much cleaner than using `.apply` with a `re.sub`.

Comment: Yeah, pandas _built-in_ functions are nice and faster.

Comment: brilliant method

Comment: my original dataset has `\n` before the numbers `8.` and `9.`. When I run this code, seems like it removes the `\n ` also. Why?

Comment: I don't think this is due to the regex pattern but to your data itself. Is it a literal `\n` or a real line break ? Can you give an example and/or a screenshot ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call string methods for a DataFrame column with

```
df["EVENT_DTL"].str.strip()
```

but `.strip()` doesn't work, because it only removed extra characters from the start and end of the string. [To remove all duplicate whitespaces you can use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string):

```
import re
import pandas as pd

d = {"EVENT_DTL": [
    "8. Background : no job / living with         marriage_virgin 9. Social status : doing pretty well with his family",
    "8. Background : Engineer / living with his mom marriage_married"
]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
pattern = re.compile(" +")
df["EVENT_DTL"] = df["EVENT_DTL"].apply(lambda x: pattern.sub(" ", x))
print(df["EVENT_DTL"][0])
```